# What is our stance on questions on annotation programs?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions on annotation programs? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Some examples of such questions below.

---

Example 1: [Configure BRAT so that if no `.ann` file is found, then an empty `.ann` file is created](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/19129/843)

> I am annotating a new corpus with BRAT. I have a set of `.txt` files to annotate. Is it possible to configure BRAT so that if no `.ann` file is found, then an empty `.ann` file is created? Or am I supposed to myself provide the empty `.ann` files?

Example 2: [Can BRAT be used for text classification annotation?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17382/843)

> [BRAT (brat rapid annotation tool)](http://brat.nlplab.org/index.html) can be used for named-entity annotation:
>
> [image]
>
> Can BRAT be used for text classification annotation? I.e., given the text, annotate whether it belongs to some classes?

Example 3: [BRAT: when annotating entities, only allow selecting tokens, not characters](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/19161/843)

[BRAT (brat rapid annotation tool)](http://brat.nlplab.org/index.html) can be used for named-entity annotation:

[image]

Does BRAT have some  option forcing the annotators to only select tokens, not characters?

For example, if the sentence is `His name is Bob Smith and he lives in the UK.`, the option would prevent the annotators from marking `s Bob Smith` as the entity. Marking `Bob Smith` or `and` would be allowed.

In addition to correctness, it would also increase the annotation time (it's faster to select tokens than characters).

Answer (score 3):

Tough call. NLP and text classification is on-topic. Tools for NLP and text classification are also on-topic in my view. So a question about, say, R and NLP is on-topic, although we've usually said that questions that are just about programming and using R at heart belong on SO. Although these concern usage of a tool too, I don't think they're relevant to SO. When in doubt I'd say leave them open.

Comment: Thanks. I have noticed that my three questions on annotation programs all got downvoted.